# Bootstrap modal background gets too dark

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

After I open my modal window, it gets darker and darker on successive openings.  On the third click to open modal, the back ground behind the modal screen is completely dark.  Seems to be cache and adding onto the faded background.  How to fix this?

Comment: More details needed. What version of Bootstrap? What browser? Does it happen on the Bootstrap demo page here [link](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)?

Comment: Are you loading a page into the modal?

Comment: Are you using the Twitter.Bootstrap NuGet package?  Have you tried using the Less version along with BundleTransformer.LESS ?

Comment: yes i am loading a page.  i am not using package, just downloaded the files and added to project.